# Postgres Where And being ignored?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to chain multiple WHERE AND statements in Postgres, however it seems they're being ignored.

My query is

```
SELECT id, title, tags, selected_preview_image, items, uid
            FROM  fb_designs r, json_array_elements(r.items#>'{listings}') obj
            WHERE  obj->>'active' = 'false' OR obj->>'active' = 'true'
            AND title LIKE '%hoot%'
            AND tags @> '{"123"}'
            GROUP BY id
```

However as you can see in the below output, its ignored the title and the tags query

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround the `OR`ed condition with parentheses

```
WHERE  
    (obj->>'active' = 'false' OR obj->>'active' = 'true')
    AND title LIKE '%hoot%'
    AND tags @> '{"123"}'
```

Or better yet, use `IN`:

```
WHERE  
    obj->>'active' IN ('false', 'true')
    AND title LIKE '%hoot%'
    AND tags @> '{"123"}'
```

Rationale: `OR` has lower prescendence than `AND`.

So this:

```
obj->>'active' = 'false' 
OR obj->>'active' = 'true'
AND title LIKE '%hoot%'
AND tags @> '{"123"}'
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
obj->>'active' = 'false' 
OR (
    obj->>'active' = 'true'
    AND title LIKE '%hoot%'
    AND tags @> '{"123"}'
)
```

As you can see, with the above expression, any record that has `obj->>'active' = 'false'` will pass through.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that did the job. Still new to Postgres so still learning!